# Finding the time of contact between two objects on the same collision path?

Tags: javascript, time, collision-detection

I'm trying to find the time it will take (if at all) two objects on a path of collision will contact, which is proving hard with a glass of wine to hand.

For arguments sake, and in JavaScript:

```
var pointA = { x: 0 }
var pointB = { x: 100 }

var pointATravelTime = 1000; // milliseconds
var pointBTravelTime = 2000; // milliseconds

var pointATimeout = setTimeout(function () {

  pointA.x = 200; // pointA will arrive here in pointATravelTime

}, pointATravelTime);

var pointBTimeout = setTimeout(function () {

  pointB.x = 0; // pointB will arrive here in pointBTravelTime

}, pointBTravelTime);
```

In theory, how can we calculate the time it will take for `pointA` and `pointB` to collide, given that they are going at different speeds?

Thanks.

Comment: If they're both travelling in the same axis, and are headed towards each other's positions, then it's just half way through their journey.

Comment: @Quill yes, both on the x axis, but at different speeds and possibly to different x positions

Comment: Find their speed and you can compare the distance

Answer (score 1):

This is not really that hard, just basic math.

pointA is moving at, let's say 100 m/s.
pointB is moving at, half of that, 50 m/s.
They're both heading towards each other

The formula would be : time = distance/velocity

Let's say the distance is 100m

in this case :

100m / (100m/s + 50m/s)

= 100/150

= 0,666..s

And there you have it. The two points will meet at 0.666s.

This is not hard to implement in any programming language, so I'm wondering why you post this sort of question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yup, not hard. And yes, basic math. I guess you missed the "glass of wine" part. Or perhaps the opportunity to look-down was too great to pass up? :-) thanks and all that.